# Network error when sending a file through http post with NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, post, nsmutableurlrequest

I have a problem using setHTTPBodyStream instead of setHTTPBody with a NSMutableURLRequest.

I'm working on code to send large file to a server through http post. With the following portion code, everything works perfectly :

```
NSData * mydata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.tmpFileLocationToUpload];
[request setHTTPBody:mydata];
```

If I change it to :

```
NSData * mydata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.tmpFileLocationToUpload];
self.tmpInputStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:mydata];
[request setHTTPBodyStream: self.tmpInputStream];
```

Then I always end with a network error : Error - The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)

The goal is at the end to create inputStrem directly from the file to be able to send large file without to load them in memory.

Did I miss something with setHTTPBodyStream use ?

Thanks for your help.

Regards.
Sébastien.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the HTTP method (if you're not already). I was able to fix a "kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303" error by adding:

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `setHTTPBody`, it automatically sets the `Content-length` header of the request, but when you use `setHTTPBodyStream`, it doesn't, but rather sets `Transfer-encoding` of `chunked`. A `chunked` transfer encoding is used when the length of the stream cannot be determined in advance.  (See [Chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).)

When using `NSURLConnection` in conjunction with `setHTTPBodyStream`, you can manually set `Content-length` and it will prevent the `Transfer-encoding` of `chunked` (assuming you know the length in advance):

```
NSString *contentLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [mydata length]];
[request setValue:contentLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
```

When using `NSURLSession`, attempts to manually set `Content-length` in conjunction with a chunked request may not prevent it from being a `chunked` request.